# RestSharp_106.3.0 failed to install on VS.NET 2017 v4.5

Tags: restsharp

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'RestSharp 106.3.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>
> At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  RestSharp -Version 106.3.0
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 4):

It worked after I changed the target framework to 4.52.

Answer (score 2):

For RestSharp 106.3.0 
its .NETFramework 4.5.2 and .NETStandard 2.0
check dependencies for this version...

check here https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp